# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'plot' with pie chart

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have grouped by a whole data frame and counted the number of rows accomplishing the condition. Then, the returned value is a integer.

```
machines_class1_grouped_with_test=machines_class1[machines_class1.CpuEff>90].groupby('Type').count().reset_index()
machines_class1_grouped_with_test['CpuEff']
```

```
0      109
1    10791
2        2
3       17
4       18
5        9
6      413
7       12
8      132
9       29
Name: CpuEff, dtype: int64
```

The issue appears when I want to plot this in a pie chart,

```
machines_class1_grouped_with_test['CpuEff'].agg(lambda x: sum(x)).plot(kind='pie',title='',figsize=(10,10))
```

but it retruns me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'plot'
```

Why does not let me plot the pie chart? I usualy do it this way, but the difference is I am not using double precission numbers or floats.

Comment: The error in your question title (which suggests that `.plot` is what is failing) is different than the error in the body of your question (which suggests that the problem is with the `sum`). Please clarify, and also please provide a [mcve] (one which has usable data rather than an unusable image).

Comment: Indeed, the error in question is the current in title. I also have included the acutal usable data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
machines_class1_grouped_with_test['CpuEff'].agg(lambda x: sum(x)).plot(kind='pie',title='',figsize=(10,10))
```

is equivalent to

```
machines_class1_grouped_with_test['CpuEff'].agg(sum).plot(kind='pie',title='',figsize=(10,10))
```

When applied to a single column (as is the case here) `.agg(sum)` just sums that one column, returning a single integer (which explains the error). It isn't clear what this aggregation is supposed to mean. Perhaps just drop that part of the expression and use

```
machines_class1_grouped_with_test['CpuEff'].plot(kind='pie',title='',figsize=(10,10))
```